# SQL Developer "missing left parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Can someone please help me?
I am trying to make this table for some coursework but I always have a problem with the foreign keys and I don't know why...

I get this error, when I try and create the table: "missing left parenthesis"

```
CREATE TABLE Avatar 
(
Avatar_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT pk_Avatar PRIMARY KEY,
AvatarName VARCHAR(255),
DOB NUMBER(12),
Gender VARCHAR(1),
Strength NUMBER(12),
Weapon VARCHAR(255),
Species VARCHAR(255),
Cost NUMBR(20),
Player_ID NUMBER(3), FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Player(Player_ID),
MotherAvatar_ID NUMBER(3), FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MotherAvatar(MotherAvatar_ID),
FatherAvatar_ID NUMBER(3), FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FatherAvatar(FatherAvatar_ID)
);
```

Comment: did you create the tables where the foreign keys are from?

Comment: change this `Cost NUMBR(20)` to `Cost NUMBER(20),`

Comment: Thank you, I will try these and get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE Avatar 
(
Avatar_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT pk_Avatar PRIMARY KEY,
AvatarName VARCHAR(255),
DOB NUMBER(12),
Gender VARCHAR(1),
Strength NUMBER(12),
Weapon VARCHAR(255),
Species VARCHAR(255),
Cost NUMBER(20),
Player_ID NUMBER(3), CONSTRAINT fk_playerid FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID) REFERENCES Player(Player_ID),
MotherAvatar_ID NUMBER(3), CONSTRAINT fk_MotherAvatar_ID FOREIGN KEY (MotherAvatar_ID) REFERENCES MotherAvatar(MotherAvatar_ID),
FatherAvatar_ID NUMBER(3),CONSTRAINT fk_FatherAvatar_ID FOREIGN KEY (FatherAvatar_ID) REFERENCES FatherAvatar(FatherAvatar_ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Added constraint keyword in your code

```
CREATE TABLE Avatar 
(
Avatar_ID NUMBER(3) CONSTRAINT pk_Avatar PRIMARY KEY,
AvatarName VARCHAR(255),
DOB NUMBER(12),
Gender VARCHAR(1),
Strength NUMBER(12),
Weapon VARCHAR(255),
Species VARCHAR(255),
Cost NUMBR(20),
Player_ID NUMBER(3), 
CONSTRAINT fk_player FOREIGN KEY (Player_ID ) REFERENCES Player(Player_ID) ,
MotherAvatar_ID NUMBER(3), 
CONSTRAINT fk_ma FOREIGN KEY (MotherAvatar_ID) REFERENCES MotherAvatar(MotherAvatar_ID),
FatherAvatar_ID NUMBER(3), 
CONSTRAINT fk_fa FOREIGN KEY (FatherAvatar_ID ) REFERENCES FatherAvatar(FatherAvatar_ID)
);
```

Comment: correct the typo, change `Cost NUMBR(20)` to `Cost NUMBER(20)`